# Custom fields in swagger generated API documentation in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, yaml, swagger

I have an ASP.NET 6 API project and I'm using Swagger to generate the documentation.

The issue now is that the customer wants a YAML file with additional properties at endpoint level, like the following (I've named them x-customer-prop-....):

```
...
/Commodities/Categories/List:
    get:
      x-customer-prop-production-ready: true
      x-customer-prop-access-policy:  open
      x-customer-prop-data-classification: public
      x-customer-prop-api-pattern: Hey Jude
      tags:
        - Commodities
      summary: Provides the list of categories.
      description: Categories are matched with high level commodity classification at level 1. \n\nNo mandatory parameter.
      parameters:
        - name: countryCode
          in: query
          description: The code to identify the country. It can be a ISO-3166 Alpha 3 code
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: categoryName
          in: query
          description: The name, even partial and case insensitive, of a commodity category.
          schema:
            type: string
```

How can I generate these properties for each endpoint?

How can I generate a YAML instead of the regular JSON?

Currently, for generating documentation I'm using the attribute on top of the method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides the list of categories.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Categories are matched with high level commodity classification at level 1. \n\nNo mandatory parameter.
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="countryCode">The code to identify the country. It can be a ISO-3166 Alpha 3 code</param>
/// <param name="categoryName">The name, even partial and case insensitive, of a commodity category.</param>
/// <param name="categoryID">The exact ID of a Commodity, as found in /Commodities/List.</param>
/// <param name="page">page number for paged results</param>
/// <param name="format">Output format: [JSON|CSV] Json is the default value</param>        /// 
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("Categories/List")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(BusinessLogic.Dto.PagedCommodityListDTO), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(BusinessLogic.Dto.BadRequestDTO), 400)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCategoriesList(string? countryCode, string? categoryName, int categoryID = 0, int page = 1, string format = "json")
....
}
```

In the startup I add the swagger generation in the following way:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(
    options =>
    {
        options.DocumentFilter<Swagger.CustomModelDocumentFilter>();
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new OpenApiInfo { 
            Title = "XXXX API", 
            Description= "API Documentation of the XXXXXX platform: ...",
            Contact = new OpenApiContact()
            {
                Name= "XXX-INFO",
                Email= "email@somewhere.com"
            },
            Version = "v1.0" });
        options.IncludeXmlComments(XmlCommentsFilePath, true);
    });
```

where the CustomModelDocumentFilter class is used to add additional properties but only at root level:

```
public class CustomModelDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        swaggerDoc.Extensions.Add("x-customer-root-prop-xxx", new CustomExtensionValue("false"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it supported from open api schema to define such properties ?

Comment: @CodingMytra yes it is

Answer (score 0):

you can add extension at endpoint level also.
you need use OperationFilter like below

```
public class MyOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        operation.Extensions.Add("x-customer-root-prop-xxx", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Any.OpenApiString("false"));
    }
}
```

and

```
options.DocumentFilter<MyOperationFilter>();
```

once you run again and see the json document , you can see these properties for each endpoint.

[image]

Comment: Note: The above might need to be options.OperationFilter<MyOperationFilter >(); if working with Asp.Net Web Api 6.0